# Spring AOP (AspectJ) with Kotlin and Gradle - I can't get it to work

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, spring-aop

I have a Spring Boot + Kotlin + Gradle project. I'd like to create a small library for my use-cases. This library should use AOP to remove some cross cutting concerns I observed.

Therefore I started adding these two dependencies to my gradle build file.

`build.gradle.kts`

```
implementation("org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.9.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.2.9.RELEASE")
```

I also added the freefair aspectj plugin due some suggestions from the interwebs.
The following aspect I created should be placed in `src/main/aspectj` according to this documentation: https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/5.2.1/reference/#_io_freefair_aspectj

> This plugin adds AspectJ support to the project, by adding a aspectj directory to every source set.
> Source contained in the src/main/aspectj directory will be compiled with ajc by the compileAspectj task.

```
plugins {
    // ...
    id("io.freefair.aspectj") version "5.2.1"
    // ...
}
```

I then started to create my first aspect that matches on every method which is annotated with `@Foozy`

`src/main/aspectj/FoozyAspect.kt` < the 'special' source path

```
@Component
@Aspect
class FoozyAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(com.client.annotation.Foozy)")
    fun doStuff() {
        LOG.info("Do Stuff")
    }

    companion object {
        private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FoozyAspect::class.java)
    }
}
```

Then I created this annotation

`src/main/kotlin/com.client.annotation/Foozy.kt`

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Foozy
```

Now to test if everything works as expected I created a unit test

`src/test/kotlin/FoozyAspectTest.kt`

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
internal class FoozyAspectTest {
    private val testCandidate: TestCandidate = TestCandidate()

    @Test
    fun `should work with aspect`() {
        testCandidate.doStuff()
    }
}
```

`src/test/TestCandidate.kt`

```
class TestCandidate {
    @Foozy
    fun doStuff(): String {
        return "stuff"
    }
}
```

### Result

Executing the text in debug mode does not yield the awaited info log `Do Stuff` and also does not cease the thread at the breakpoint in the `FoozyAspect.kt` **doStuff()** method.
I have no idea what to configure here.
For good reason I kinda have the suspicion that I am mixing up different "ways" to get this to work or am just missing some final steps in preconfiguration/prerequisites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AspectJ compiler can't compile Kotlin source code. Your `.kt` file in `src/main/aspectj` will be completely ignored.

You have different options depending on what you really want to do:

Do you want your Aspect to be woven by ajc at compile-time, or do you just want to use "plain" Spring AOP?

The differences are explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-choosing

If you just want to use Spring AOP, you dont need a special gradle plugin. Just put your `.kt` file in `src/main/kotlin` and follow the Spring AOP docs.

If you want to weave your aspect at compile-time with ajc, you have two options:

1. Keep the `io.freefair.aspectj` plugin to compile an weave the aspect in one step: Implement your aspect as `.java` or `.aj` so it can be compiled by ajc
2. Switch to the `io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving` plugin in order to separate the compilation an weaving steps: In this case you can keep your Aspect implementation as Kotlin, but you have to put it in `src/main/kotlin`. Your Aspect will then be compiled by kotlinc and then woven by ajc.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the 347th duplicate of a classical Spring AOP question: If you read the manual, you will notice that Spring AOP only works for Spring components, e.g. declared via `@Component` or `@Bean`.

Your `TestCandidate` seems to be a POJO, so Spring does not know about it. Also if you make it a component, make sure you get an instance from the container and do not just create one via constructor call in your test.

Comment: Ok will try. I thought only the Aspect needs the @Component so the weaving can be "started" by Spring. Since AssertJ is looking for a method having an applied annotation I see no reason the class having this method needs to be in Spring's context - since it's AspectJ looking for it and not Spring.

Comment: Are you talking about AssertJ or AspectJ? They are not the same. Furthermore, AspectJ and Spring AOP are not the same either. You tagged the question _spring-aop_, so I was assuming that this is what you use. For real AspectJ the aspect would not need to be a Spring component, which is another clue that you want to use Spring AOP. In that case, both the aspect and its target classes need to be Spring managed beans. Don't assume, read documentation and sample code. 

Comment: Oah dang I always mix the two terms up. I meant AspectJ

Comment: Sample code for what? I told you what to do already, please try that first. If it does not work, then how about you showing me an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first? Ideally, this would be a GitHub project with Maven build (Gradle, if must be). I am still not sure if you use AspectJ or Spring AOP and how you configured it. Besides, I do not speak Kotlin.